# Counting how many times .replace() is called during script in python?

Tags: python

I'm using this code to work on files related to GIS:

```
import os

path = r"P:/test test"
under_score = [' ', '!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '_-_']
dot = ['.',',']


for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
for f in files:
    copy_f = f
    for char in copy_f:
        if (char in under_score): copy_f = copy_f.replace(char, '_')
        if (char in dot): copy_f = copy_f.replace(char, "") 
    os.rename(f,copy_f)
```

Is there any way for me to add a .count() to find out how many characters were replaced when I run this script on a particular path?

Comment: This is off-topic here and would be better asked (and possibly already has been) on [SO]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a variable to count when the `if` is entered:

```
replaceCount = 0
for f in files:
    copy_f = f
    for char in copy_f:
        if (char in under_score):
            replaceCount += 1
            copy_f = copy_f.replace(char, '_')
        if (char in dot): 
            replaceCount += 1
            copy_f = copy_f.replace(char, "") 
    os.rename(f,copy_f)

print replaceCount
```

The `print` statement at the end will return the number of times the `if` statements were entered (and therefore the number of times the `replace` was used).